# How to slide to particular HTML element using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

How to set focus  and slide down to the html when button is clicked . How to slide to particular HTML element using javascript?

```css
p:focus, p:active {
  color: green;
}
p {
 min-height: 250px;
}
```

```html
<body>


<input type="button" onclick="getfocus()" value="Get focus">
<input type="button" onclick="losefocus()" value="Lose focus">

<p>Click the buttons to give focus and/or remove focus from the link above.</p>
<p>Click the buttons to give focus and/or remove focus from the link above.</p>
<p>Click the buttons to give focus and/or remove focus from the link above.</p>
<p id="myAnchor">Click the buttons to give focus and/or remove focus from the link above.</p>

<script>
function getfocus() {
  document.getElementById("myAnchor").focus();
}

function losefocus() {
  document.getElementById("myAnchor").blur();
}
</script>

</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding `tabindex="0"` to `p#myAnchor` solves the issue

> `tabindex="0"` means that the element should be focusable in sequential
> keyboard navigation, after any positive tabindex values and its order
> is defined by the document's source order.

```js
function getfocus() {
  document.getElementById("myAnchor").focus();
}

function losefocus() {
  document.getElementById("myAnchor").blur();
}
```

```css
p:focus,
p:active {
  color: green;
}

p {
  min-height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<input type="button" onclick="getfocus()" value="Get focus">
<input type="button" onclick="losefocus()" value="Lose focus">

<p>Click the buttons to give focus and/or remove focus from the link above.</p>
<p>Click the buttons to give focus and/or remove focus from the link above.</p>
<p>Click the buttons to give focus and/or remove focus from the link above.</p>
<p tabindex="0" id="myAnchor">Click the buttons to give focus and/or remove focus from the link above.</p>
```

Comment: Its creating border too, which i dont want to additionally add into it.

Answer (score 0):

If by get focus you mean get there:

```
function getfocus() {
  document.getElementById("myAnchor").scrollIntoView();
}
```

and if by loose focus if you mean going back to the top:

```
function looseFocus(){
window.scrollTo(0, 0);
}
```

but `<p>` is not focusable.
If you really want focus you need an anchor `<p><a id="myAnchor" href="#">Click the buttons to give focus and/or remove focus from the link above.</a></p>`

Comment: almost, not quite tho :{